# Get all class names in a Python package

Tags: python, class

I need to get the list of all classes in Python package.
At first I get all filenames (it works fine, took it from stackoverflow):

```
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = getcwd()
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
```

Then I inspect all files and it doesn't work properly:

```
for x in onlyfiles:
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(x):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            print obj
```

The output is:

```
<type 'str'>
....
<type 'str'>
```

However, the following code works properly:

```
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(example.py):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            print obj
```

Could you help me to figure out what the mistake is?

Comment: What does the last chunk of code output that makes it correct?

Comment: It outputs example.ClassA. If a explicitly name the module like this   inspect.getmembers(example.py) it works

Comment: Are you sure you're really passing `example.py` and not `example` after doing an `import example`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`inspect.getmembers()` works on *objects*, and you are passing in strings. Python doesn't know these strings contain filenames or will treat these filenames as modules to import.

You'd have to import the files for `inspect.getmembers()` to work. Because you are working with files in the current directory, you should be able to just import them all:

```
import importlib

for x in onlyfiles:
    module = importlib.import_module(x)
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            print obj
```

Note that [`inspect.getmembers()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) accepts a second argument, the predicate that lets you filter what the method returns. Instead of filtering manually, you could just use `inspect.isclass()` as the predicate here:

```
for x in onlyfiles:
    module = importlib.import_module(x)
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass):
        print obj
```

Comment: You could also save a step by telling `inspect.getmembers` to do the filtering by passing `inspect.isclass` as a second parameter

Comment: Thank you for the amazing reply, I messed up strings and filenames! Should the same work when I have several subfolders with tests? What I have: several folders with some Python files in each of them. I need to get all class name from them to start all the tests.

Comment: @Konstantin: Do those subfolders have `__init__.py` files? They either need to be packages (so `importlib.import_module(filename, package='dirname')` will work) or you need to add the subfolder to `sys.path` so Python can find those files when importing.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, using the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/inspect.html) module:

```
import sys
import inspect

clsmembers = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass)
```

This runs within a live file.

Comment: This was a really good answer. imo it should be bumped up.